# Filter/Sort user comments PHP

Tags: php

I'm a php newb so you'll have to bear with me. I'm working on a user comment section where people can submit condition/snow reports for some backcountry cabins. I've got the submission and display part down but I'd like people to be able to filter the observations by hut so they can choose to see just the reports for a particular hut. I feel like I'm close but can't seem to get the code to work. This is still just an in house mockup so that is why there's no spam filter yet and some of the code may look a bit sloppy (inline styles, etc.) Thanks in advance, any suggestions are appreciated.

PHP Code

```
if (isset($_GET['search']))
{
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
try
{
$sql = "SELECT name, comment, date, hutname FROM `comments` WHERE hut LIKE hutname ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC"; 

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error fetching comments: ' . $e->getMessage();
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
$comments[] = array(
'name' => $row['name'],
'date' => $row['date'],
'hutname' => $row['hutname'],
'comment' => $row['comment']
);
}
}

if (isset($_POST['comment']))
{
try
{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO comments SET
comment = :comment,
name = :name,
contact = :contact,
hutname = :hutname,
date = CURDATE(),
time = CURTIME()';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':comment', $_POST['comment']);
$s->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
$s->bindValue(':hutname', $_POST['hut']);
$s->bindValue(':contact', $_POST['email']);
$s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error adding submitted observation: ' . $e->getMessage();
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}
header('Location: .');
exit();
}


try
{
$sql = "SELECT name, comment, date, hutname FROM `comments` ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error fetching comments: ' . $e->getMessage();
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
$comments[] = array(
'name' => $row['name'],
'date' => $row['date'],
'hutname' => $row['hutname'],
'comment' => $row['comment']
);
}



include 'comments.html.php';
```

HTML Code

```
<body>
<?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="eight large-8 columns">
<h4>Here are the most current conditions:</h4>
<form action="" method="get">
     <div class="row">
    <div class=" large-5 columns">
    <label>Sort by Hut:</label>
    <select name="hut" id="hut">
    <optgroup label="10th Mountain Huts">
    <option value="10th Mountain Division Hut">10th Mountain Division Hut</option>
    <option value="Benedict Huts">Benedict Huts</option>
    <option value="Betty Bear Hut">Betty Bear Hut</option>
    <option value="Continental Divide Cabin">Continental Divide Cabin</option>
    <option value="Point Breeze Cabin">Point Breeze Cabin</option>
    <option value="Eiseman Hut">Eiseman Hut</option>
    <option value="Fowler/Hilliard Hut">Fowler/Hilliard Hut</option>
    <option value="Harry Gates Hut">Harry Gates Hut</option>
    <option value="Jackal Hut">Jackal Hut</option>
    <option value="Margy's Hut">Margy's Hut</option>
    <option value="MacNamara Hut">MacNamara Hut</option>
    <option value="Peter Estin Hut">Peter Estin Hut</option>
    <option value="Polar Star Inn">Polar Star Inn</option>
    <option value="Carl's Cabin">Carl's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Sangree M. Froelicher Hut">Sangree M. Froelicher Hut</option>
    <option value="Shrine Mountain Inn">Shrine Mountain Inn</option>
    <option value="Skinner Hut">Skinner Hut</option>
    <option value="Uncle Bud's Hut">Uncle Bud's Hut</option>
    <option value="Vance's Cabin">Vance's Cabin</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Summit Huts">
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Francie's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Janet's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Ken's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Section House</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Grand Huts">
    <option value="Broome Hut">Broome Hut</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Braun &amp Friends Huts">
    <option value="Barnard Hut">Barnard Hut</option>
    <option value="Goodwin Greene Hut">Goodwin Greene Hut</option>
    <option value="Lindley Hut">Lindley Hut</option>
    <option value="Markley Hut">Markley Hut</option>
    <option value="Opa's Taylor Hut">Opa's Taylor Hut</option>
    <option value="Tagert &amp Green-Wilson Huts">Tagert &amp Green-Wilson Huts</option>
    <option value="Friends Hut">Friends Hut</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="search">Sort</button>
    </div>

</form>
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
<div class="hutConditions">
<h6><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment ['date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?> &nbsp <?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment ['hutname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?></h6>
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment ['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?></p>
<blockquote>
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment ['comment'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>
</p>
</blockquote>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<div class="four large-4 columns">
<h5>Submit an Observation:</h5>
<form action="?" method="post">
<div>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<label for="hut">Hut</label>
<select name="hut" id="hut">
    <optgroup label="10th Mountain Huts">
    <option value="10th Mountain Division Hut">10th Mountain Division Hut</option>
    <option value="Benedict Huts">Benedict Huts</option>
    <option value="Betty Bear Hut">Betty Bear Hut</option>
    <option value="Continental Divide Cabin">Continental Divide Cabin</option>
    <option value="Point Breeze Cabin">Point Breeze Cabin</option>
    <option value="Eiseman Hut">Eiseman Hut</option>
    <option value="Fowler/Hilliard Hut">Fowler/Hilliard Hut</option>
    <option value="Harry Gates Hut">Harry Gates Hut</option>
    <option value="Jackal Hut">Jackal Hut</option>
    <option value="Margy's Hut">Margy's Hut</option>
    <option value="MacNamara Hut">MacNamara Hut</option>
    <option value="Peter Estin Hut">Peter Estin Hut</option>
    <option value="Polar Star Inn">Polar Star Inn</option>
    <option value="Carl's Cabin">Carl's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Sangree M. Froelicher Hut">Sangree M. Froelicher Hut</option>
    <option value="Shrine Mountain Inn">Shrine Mountain Inn</option>
    <option value="Skinner Hut">Skinner Hut</option>
    <option value="Uncle Bud's Hut">Uncle Bud's Hut</option>
    <option value="Vance's Cabin">Vance's Cabin</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Summit Huts">
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Francie's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Janet's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Ken's Cabin</option>
    <option value="Francie's Cabin">Section House</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Grand Huts">
    <option value="Broome Hut">Broome Hut</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Braun &amp Friends Huts">
    <option value="Barnard Hut">Barnard Hut</option>
    <option value="Goodwin Greene Hut">Goodwin Greene Hut</option>
    <option value="Lindley Hut">Lindley Hut</option>
    <option value="Markley Hut">Markley Hut</option>
    <option value="Opa's Taylor Hut">Opa's Taylor Hut</option>
    <option value="Tagert &amp Green-Wilson Huts">Tagert &amp Green-Wilson Huts</option>
    <option value="Friends Hut">Friends Hut</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<label for="comment">Conditions/Observations:</label>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="3" cols="40">
</textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" value="Add">Submit Observations</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Yay a PHP newbie using PDO - well done.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exactly it is you want to achieve and where your previous attempts failed you? Also please reduce the code to all relevant parts (we're not interested in your stylesheets etc.). Additionally if you have larger parts, please properly format (that means indentation!) them, so they can be read more easy.

Comment: `LIKE` requires string after to be surrounded with quotes `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Fabio said

[LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) must be enclosing with quotes.

```
 SELECT     name, comment, date, hutname 
 FROM       `comments` 
 WHERE      hut LIKE 'hutname' 
 ORDER BY   date DESC, time DESC
```

or the wildcard if you need more generals results

```
 SELECT     name, comment, date, hutname 
 FROM       `comments` 
 WHERE      hut LIKE '%hutname%' 
 ORDER BY   date DESC, time DESC
```

Read the LIKE section in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

**Note:**
try eneable display_errors in php in the dev enviroment using

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

or in the php.ini to get the errors and should be more easy the debug proccess

Comment: Sorry for the excess code, first time I've asked a question here. The default view is all of the comments sorted by date. I want people to be able to filter the comments so they only see comments for a certain cabin by choosing one from the drop down menu at the top of the page. I added quotes and wildcards but still nothing. I'll try enabling display errors and see if I can't get it figured out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to check if you have sql or php error, try running the query directly in mysql, in PDo you can debug in this way http://us1.php.net/PDOStatement.errorInfo, the first step it's find where is the error

Answer (score 0):

try using adding a wildcard for the like statment. you have:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, comment, date, hutname FROM `comments` WHERE hut LIKE hutname ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
```

try

```
$sql = "SELECT name, comment, date, hutname 
FROM `comments` WHERE hut LIKE '%hutname%' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
```

or I would also pull 'id' of each hut or something more standard than the cabin name:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, comment, date, hutname 
FROM `comments` WHERE hut = 'hut_id' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
```

Comment: LIKE %% without quotes?

Comment: I think he's looking for equal result so he won't need wildcards

Comment: i think so to but wildcards will ensure a match even with formatting issues.